# Update view based on hierarchical select

Tags: views, users

When a student goes to register they select their state and then their school (the state and school are stored as taxonomies). What I have not been able to figure out is, then the possible teachers needs to only display the teachers associated with that school and an option for not listed. The teachers are being pulled from a view that displays their username and then first and last name in brackets. Attached on the users profile and the view the teacher field is using. The contextual filters is set for a display all.[image: Profile]

[image: Drupal View]